# Xcode: Product name or codename for project file name(.xcodeproj)?

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, projects-and-solutions

I'm now changing project file name of Xcode because my **product** name(app name) was changed.
And I got some problem due to changing project file name.(*This is not the question for this time. I also know I can change app name by `bundle display name` setting)

I think I should have used codename(instead of product name) for project file name.
If I did so, I don't need to change project name forever.

Will I have any troubles if I use codename for Xcode project file?
(for example, will apple reject the app?)

Which is commonly used for project file, product name or codename?
How about your project file?

For example, code name of Windows Vista is `Longhorn`.
I guess project file name of Windows Vista was not vista but Longhorn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no issues with naming your xcode project something different than the application. The display name is what matters to Apple and your users.

The second part of the question is not fit for Stack Overflow to answer, programmers.stackexchange might be a better fit.

Comment: thanks. this is second time I got advice to go programmers today. I read [choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-stack-exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82988/) but I still don't understand difference between stackoverflow and programers.

Comment: programmers is for discussions, stackoverflow is for discrete questions. "Is this a good idea?" is a question for programmers, "How do I do X?" is a question for stackoverflow.